# Bash script to copy directory to multiple other directories

Tags: macos, bash

I have two directories, `src` and `build`.

Within `src` I have a folder called `core` which is where all updates are made.

Within `build` I have several folders with different names and each of those folders have the same folder structure as `src`.

What I am trying to do is copy the `core` folder from `src` into each of the `build` sub-directories.

I have tried using

```
cp -r /src/core /build/*
```

and also

```
cp -r /src/core/ /build/*/
```

Any help would be appreciated, and an explanation of how it works would be great!

Thank you :)

Comment: you need to run `cp -rf source for-each-dir` for that you need to run it inside a for loop. `ls -d /build/*/` will give you all the dir names, `for i in $(ls -d /build/*/); do cp -rf /src/code/ $i/; done` might be a solution. Also look into `rsync` which is better suited for these kind of jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single 'cp' is going to do a single copy of everything somewhere. It doesn't support multiple copies to multiple destinations simultaneously. The shell will expand your command line to a number of sources and one destination.

You could use a for loop:

```
for dest in /build/*; do cp -r /src/core $dest; done
```

Comment: thank you very much! this worked when pasted into the command line, but when i tried to add it as an alias it gave me to cp options. any idea why? thanks

Comment: Did you encapsulate the string? With quotes, for example? `alias name='code here'`

Comment: @SunSparc yeah i wrote it as so : `alias src2build = "for dest in /build/*; do cp -r /src/core $dest; done" `

Comment: and it outputs `usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
`

Comment: I tried using the alias method and it's persnickety about the wildcard. The most consistent, predictable results occurred when I escape-quoted the asterisk, but even then the alias would give a different result the first time I ran it versus subsequent times. I'd toss it in a bash file and be done with it. ;)

Comment: haha oh my that's strange! i'd love to do that, however, i literally have no idea how.. any suggestions? thanks @mbratch

Comment: OK I got it: `alias mycp="for dest in /build/*; do cp -r /src/core \$dest; done"` Note the backslash on the $.

Comment: You're a genius!! thank you!! is there anyway i can upvote you?

Comment: Odd, I tried the original alias on both OS X and Ubuntu and it worked. Tried it multiple times, with single quotes and with double quotes.

Comment: Don't trust it! It all depends upon what $dest was set to last. The \$dest ensures you get the one generated by the `for` loop.